# Delete semi duplicate files

Tags: file, batch-file

I'm wondering if there is a way to remove semi-duplicate files **(name based)** using a batch file or any other means (freeware utility) in Windows?

To give an example I have following files in a directory:

- `fileNameXXX(aaa).ext`
- `fileNameXXX(bbb).ext`

In this case, I only want to keep the `fileNameXXX(bbb).ext`

Comment: and how do you decide that  `(bbb)` is the one you want to keep?

Comment: I should have taken better examples, but let's say it's language specific. So in this case bbb would be (Dutch). So I would like to only keep all Dutch files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's a single line in batch:

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b "*(*).ext" ^| find /v "(ddd)"') do ECHO del "%%f"
```

For every file matching the filemask excluding files with `(ddd)` do: delete it.

Remove the `ECHO` if the output fits your needs.

Note: if you want to use it directly on command line (instead in a batch file), replace every `%%f` with `%f`.

Tip: think about using some more code to check, if there **is**  a Dutch version, and if not, keep the English one (or whatever you prefer).